# Iterating over json gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Using this code to access the elements of a json array :

```
var json = "{\"noteDetailList\": [ {\"linkName\": \"test1\"}]}"

 $.each(json, function() {
                        console.log(data)
                    });
```

to iterate gives this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '43' in {"noteDetailList": [ {"linkName": "test1"}]} jquery-1.11.0.js:592isArraylike jquery-1.11.0.js:592jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.11.0.js:359(anonymous function) (index):24jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.11.0.js:4624elemData.handle jquery-1.11.0.js:4292
```

fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/rsv0tn5e/1/

Am I not iterating correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trying to iterate over a string!. Either parse the JSON into an object or use and actual object:

```js
var jsonString = "{\"noteDetailList\": [ {\"linkName\": \"test1\"}]}";
var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);

// OR

var jsonObj = {
  noteDetailList: [
    {linkName: "test1"}
  ]
};

iterateOverResult(json);
iterateOverResult(jsonObj);

function iterateOverResult(json) {
  $.each(json, function(data) {
    alert(data.toString());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse it like:

```
JSON.parse(json);
```

Try it now:

```
var json = "{\"noteDetailList\": [ {\"linkName\": \"test1\"}]}";

$.each(JSON.parse(json), function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```